# How to create a drop-down list in a excel file with data coming from another Excel file used like database?

Tags: excel, ado.net, vba

I'm using an Excel file like a Database. 
I have another Excel file that need to be filled with information coming from the Excel file Database. 
Is it possible for the Excel Database file to populate lists into my other excel file ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Under the Developer tab in Excel you can select 'Insert' and then 'Listbox'.  Create your list box in excel, then right click the box and press "Format Control".  Under the "Control" tab, you can change your Input range which can be used across different worksheets thus creating a list.  From there you can assign macros of your choice such as a ListBox_Change macro.

Typically you can make a list box in Excel using Data Validation, but that will only work within the same workbook.

Comment: You can use the first option I mentioned across different workbooks. When setting the Source Control, you select the range you want the data to come from; just select the workbook and range you want. Unless you have the workbooks open as separate processes, then you will need to use VBA:

1) Open the workbook with the data on it
2) Store the data you want inserted into the List Box
3) Go back to the workbook with the List Box in it
4) Append the stored data to the List Box

I think you can do the first option, but if not there are posts here with how to create List Boxes with VBA